# Is there any ability to use regex to select the classes?

Tags: css, sass, less

I know that there is ability to use the wildcard to select the elements in the page, like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

But I want to use the regex in the classes names like this

```css
div.col-*-2-* {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1-1-1">Don't select</div>
<div class="col-1-2-1">Select</div>
<div class="col-3-2-3">Select</div>
<div class="col-4-2-1">Select</div>
<div class="col-5-3-2">Don't select</div>
```

Comment: Don't use classes like this. You'll spend the rest of your life constructing class names, and then trying to decipher them (and may not be able to do that anyway, as you've found). Instead, if the second digit refers to "type", for example, use a separate class called `type-2` etc. Then you can address it in a CSS rule with `.type-2 { color: green; }`1 with no further ado.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I want to reduce my CSS code, For that I search about any way to use wildcards in the class names

Comment: It's bad practice. Find another approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is great. But the answer is NO.

There's no usage about the regular expression in css like what you stated.

For your solution, you can use like this:

```css
[class*="col-1-2-"],[class*="col-2-2-"],[class*="col-3-2-"],[class*="col-4-2-"],[class*="col-5-2-"]{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1-1-1">Don't select</div>
<div class="col-1-2-1">Select</div>
<div class="col-3-2-3">Select</div>
<div class="col-4-2-1">Select</div>
<div class="col-5-3-2">Don't select</div>
```

As per your comment, you can use like this:

```
[class="col-1-2-1"],[class="col-2-2-1"],
[class="col-3-2-1"],[class="col-4-2-1"],
[class="col-5-2-1"]{
      color: green;
    }
```

As per the @RickHitchcock answer, you can implement like this to meet your requirment:

```
[class^="col-"][class*="-2-"][class$="-1"]:not([class^="col-2"]) {
  color: green;
}
```

**Footnote:**

As @torazaburo, Do not use weird constructed classnames and then try to do regexp-like stuff to address them. Instead, use multiple classes that allow you to address elements directly.

Comment: Great reply, Thanks a lot, But I want to select the third variable also like col-wildcard-wildcard-1 :)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Comment: This will select elements with classes such as `foobar-col-1-2`. Bottom line: do not use weird constructed classnames and then try to do regexp-like stuff to address them. Instead, use multiple classes that allow you to address elements directly.

Comment: Yeah. Agree that. So upvoted your comment above. I'll also include your comment in my post if this is okay.

Comment: Deleted my answer, because yours is more thorough, and there is no completely effective way to emulate regex in CSS selectors.

Comment: @torazaburo I ensured that will not select `foobar-col-1-2` :) https://jsfiddle.net/ayf1mrho/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will use with few modifying in my html and css code

Comment: I will try to add some letters before the numbers like this col-fi1-se2-th3

Comment: @Egyptian Well, now you are violating your own rule of "reducing your CSS code". In that case, just write `class="col fi1 se2 th3"` and you can then do exactly what you want with `.se2 { color: green; }` without having to use awkward regexp-like features. BTW, you do know that elements can have multiple classes, right?